# Two TextViews should occupy minimum height

Tags: android, textview

I have a LinearLayout with 2 `TextView`s aligned horizontally. First must be left aligned, second must be right aligned in a screen (a space between them exists). I want the text to fill a screen so that it occupies as less space as possible. Also, if the text is too short, it should occupy whole screen line, not half.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:text="Example of code" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="Sample text here, it shouldn't occupy much space" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this in XML?

**Update**

First and second `TextView`s can be different length.

A layout now is displayed so: [image].

And I want it to be like so: [image: so].

**Update 2**

One layout that is a bit better than in the beginning. That's not all I want, but solves one problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:text="Example of code" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="Sample text here, it shouldn't occupy much space" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear please post an image of how you would like to have.

Comment: change height of textview to wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you check this one if it's not just send me the format you want i will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    tools:text="Awesome" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nice"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:text="Welcome"
    android:gravity="end" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thank you

Comment: Thanks, at least, in my case it works as expected. I replaced some attributes (...Right, ...Left) with corresponding names. Also deleted a central View with weight = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this into both of your 2 TextView tags, would it do what you need?

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:gravity="start" //left allign
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" // for spacing between two
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Example of code" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="end"   // right allign
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" // for spacing between two
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Sample text here, it shouldn't occupy much space" />

</LinearLayout>
```

equal layout weight divide the width available equally, increase the weight for the TextView that needs more space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got your question, but you can add a view between those text views, or use a `RelativeLayout` as parent and set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the second text child;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:text="Example of code" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:text="long long long " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly. Try the "text view" in the right match_parent and gravity "end".

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:text="Example of code"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Sample text here, it should not occupy much space" />


</LinearLayout>
```